# "keytool" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: java, android, firebase, cmd

Estoy tratando de implementar Firebase en mi aplicación de Android Studio y como quiero usar Firebase Auth necesito el Certificado de firma SHA-1, y para obtenerlo necesito ejecutar este código en el CMD:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Pero me sale:

> "keytool" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo
> programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Y eso que ya intente haciendo cd en la carpeta **`.android`** y *JAVA* ya esta en el *path* y ya agregue la variable *JAVA_HOME*.

¿Que hago?

Comment: crea una activity de google maps y en el xml viene incluido la clave

Comment: Recuerda que keytool se encuentra dentro del folder \bin ¡

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El problema que comentas

> "keytool" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa
> o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Se debe a que donde tratas de ejecutar `keytool` en realidad no existe, si no esta definido el directorio en las variables de ambiente en windows simplemente no podras accesarlo desde cualquier folder, asegura el path este correctamente definido (Cuando defines una variable de ambiente en las versiones actuales de Windows me parece que no es necesario un reinicio de tu pc, pero podría ser una opción).

Si aseguras que la ruta definida es la correcta en la variable `%JAVA_HOME%`, realiza el cambio a tu directorio en la linea de comandos de esta forma

```
cd %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

**recuerda que `keytool` se encuentra en el directorio `\bin` de tu instalación de JAVA** (por ejemplo en mi caso es `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin`) , posteriormente

realiza la operacion que deseas

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 4):

En mi caso -usando windows 10 y PowerShell- tuve que añadir "**./**" al inicio del comando, así:

```
./keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el SHA-1, a mi me funcionó con

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

Lo ví en la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth#using_gradles_signing_report)

Answer (score 0):

A mi se me presentaba el error porque estaba ejecuando el comando en el directorio incorrecto.
Una vez abri el CMD como administrador y me diriji a la ruta de donde tenía instalado la versión de mi JAVA e ingrese a la carpeta bin, alli ejecute nuevaente el comando y menciono.

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de resolverlo es poniendo un `./` al principio del comando `keytool`, en la ruta de tu Java folder. Por ejemplo en mi caso es así:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin>
```

Una vez estés en el directorio de java y la carpeta *bin*, vas a ejecutar el siguiente código en la Powershell, como administrador. Asegúrate de cambiar la ruta por tu nombre de usuario para que sea correcto.

```
./keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\Usuario\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Y listo: una vez que des enter ya te va a devolver el Sha1 y el Sha256 para utilizar en tu flutter application.

Comment: No olvides explicar qué hace el comando que has puesto en la respuesta. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.