# Problema al Generar Keystore para android

Tags: android-studio, apk, keystore

Lo que pasa es que estoy tratando de generar una keystore para mi aplicación que cree pero el problema es que no me funciona el comando de consola en cmd,  tengo windows y en android studio no me aparece la opción para generar una `keystore`
En la consola del cmd me dice que no se reconoce el `keytool`,  este es el comando que use en cmd:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -dname "C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug"
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Si me funciono muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El error que obtienes es:

> 'Keytool' command is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file

Keytool es una utilería de Java pero puedes encontrarla dentro de tu Android Studio, en mi caso por ejemplo tengo instalado android studio en la ruta:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se debe localizar dentro de tu Android Studio en `\jre\bin` por lo tanto desde la linea de comandos accede a este directorio:

```
> cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
```

ahí puedes usar la útileria `keytool.exe`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Puedes también buscar `Keytool.exe` dentro de la instalación de Java, revisa:

["keytool" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93157/keytool-no-se-reconoce-como-un-comando-interno-o-externo-programa-o-archivo-p)