# Borrar key.jks flutter

Tags: android, flutter, vscode, dart

tengo un proyecto pero tiene su propia key.jks, quiero borrarla y hacer la mía con mis datos, como podría hacer eso? Solo encuentro como recuperar la contraseña.

---

He intentado con

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore android/app/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

, me pide la contraseña del key anterior.
Con

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

, al momento poner la contraseña

```
Enter key password for <upload> (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

Me da el error de que no encontró la ruta especificada.

[image: Error no encontro la ruta especificada]

Comment: leiste la documentación oficial? https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore ahí indican como crear tu propia llave,  si la app ya está en el store, necesitas usar las llaves originales, de lo contrario no podrás subir updates y necesitarás crear una app nueva

Comment: Importante agregar como la trataste de generar por favor Sebastian, revisa [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto a :

> tengo un proyecto pero tiene su propia key.jks, quiero borrarla y
> hacer la mía con mis datos

Si subiste una aplicación que fue firmada previamente con un keystore, debes usar el mismo para poder subir actualizaciones de la aplicación, si creas uno nuevo no te permitirá actualizar la aplicación, tendría que ser una nueva aplicación.

Para crearla, usa la utilería [Keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html)

primeramente [ubica la utilería](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93157/keytool-no-se-reconoce-como-un-comando-interno-o-externo-programa-o-archivo-p/93217#93217), en mi caso se ubica en :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin
```

ahora en la ubicación de keytool.exe

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore <ubicación y nombre>.keystore -alias "alias" -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Revisa la documentación de Flutter.

[Crear un Keystore](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore)

---

En cuanto a el error :

El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta específica, se refiere a que la ruta que defines no existe, primero revisa que exista para poder generar tu certificado.

Answer (score 0):

como te dice Jorgesys, si ya subiste una app a la play store, debes seguir usando la misma key, porque de lo contrario te tocaria crear una nueva aplicación en la consola de google play y esa nueva app debe tener un package name diferente.

Si ese no es el caso, y solo quieres usar una llave con tus datos personalizados, para cargar por primera vez una app a la play store, el codigo de **keytool** es este (Para Windows)

> Antes de generar tu nueva key, asegurate que no sea el mismo nombre ni
> el mismo alias que ya tienes, pon uno nuevo, tambien verifica la ruta
> donde vas a poner tu key, osea c:\Users\TU_USUARIO\key-upload2.jks

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\TU_USUARIO\key-upload2.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload2
```

Con eso desde la linea de comandos te perira que asignes una contraseña 2 veces,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego te pedira unos datos personales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego debes escribir **si**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y por ultimo dar enter para que use la misma clave del almacen de claves en la clave actual(Osea la contraseña que escribiste ya 2 veces)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es todo lo que debes hacer, ya el archivo deberia estar en la ubicación que estableciste.

**IMPORTANTE**

> Debes asegurarte de guardar la llave par poder actualizar a futuro tu
> aplicación, si lo pierdes deberas crear otra aplicación en la consola
> de google play y modificar el nombre de tu paquete para poder usar un
> nuevo key.