# SHA1 de un proyecto de android studio

Tags: android-studio

No soy capaz de averiguar la huella digital (SHA1) de un proyecto de android studio. Desde a que ha cambiado a la version de android studio es Chipmunk 2021.2.1 y desde la pestaña Gradel ya no viene lo mismo que antes.

¿Como lo puedo sacar el SHA1 de ese proyecto aunque sea por terminal?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza este comando:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\NOMBRE_DEL_ARCHIVO_DE_USUARIO\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Si te devuelve el siguiente error:

> "keytool" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

ya ha sido resuleto en este post: [Post con problema solucionado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93157/keytool-no-se-reconoce-como-un-comando-interno-o-externo-programa-o-archivo-p)

Comment: ok pero me dice que keytool no reconoce este comando interno o externo.

Comment: Revisa el post que he subido a la respuesta